# Data manipulation with loadash (sort of join left)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

After [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809252/data-manipulation-in-datatables/40810392#40810392), I want to achieve a simplest data manipulation using lodash.

But I really don't know how to do it.

[I've set a Jsfiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentle/wj4jvfp8/)

Problem:

```
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr"];
var cashflows = [
    {'month':'jan', 'value':10}, 
  {'month':'mar', 'value':20}
  ];
```

I want :

```
[
  {'month':'jan', 'value':10},
  {'month':'feb', 'value':''},
  {'month':'mar', 'value':20},
  {'month':'apr', 'value':''}
];
```

Note: I want the solution with the less calls to losash functions, in order to improve readability.

Comment: you can use each and find lodash to get specific result. https://jsfiddle.net/wj4jvfp8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a lodash solution that [**maps**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#map) over the months array to create the structure you want:

```
var result = _.map(months, function(month){
    return {
        month: month,
        value: _.chain(cashflows)
            .find({month: month})
            .get('value', '')
            .value();
    }
});
```

The value for each month is returned from the cashflows using [**find**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#find). If no cashflow is found then [**get**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#get) will use the default value, which here is the empty string.

Comment: best solution since it uses lodash. I've learned .chain, .get and .find, thks

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could use a hash table for the given data and rebuild the result based on the `months` order.

```js
var months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr'],
    cashflows = [{ month: 'jan', value: 10 }, { month: 'mar', value: 20 }],
    result = months.map(function (m) {
        return this[m] || { month: m, value: '' };
    }, cashflows.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.month] = a;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```